# Wordpress gravity forms how to add pagination when entries are viewed in frontend

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity form of Wordpress and showed its entry on Frontend
with R & D I found the query which show the entries but i am not able to add pagination and sort order in this

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries(
    $form_id, 
    array(),
    null, 
    array('offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 99999)
);
```

Many thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarize yourself to the structure of the [function `GFAPI::get_entries`](https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#get-entries). Try the following keeping in mind that the sorting key (5) is just an example and you should use your own sorting key:

```
$search_criteria = array(); // or $search_criteria['status'] = 'active';
$sorting         = array( 'key' => '5', 'direction' => 'ASC' );  //5 is just an example
$paging          = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 25 );
$entries         = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging );
```